# How to understand spin-phonon coupling in any material? Differs from electron-phonon coupling?

Tags: condensed-matter, phonons, spin-models

Spin-phonon coupling is an interesting phenomena, especially, in the case of multiferroic materials. Its origin is said to be the exchange interaction of magnetic ions. In that case, any magnetic materials should have significant spin-phonon coupling. But we never see this phenomena in all magnetic materials. Is there any good explanation for this phenomena with some references, books, and reviews?

Comment: I don't understand the second question in your heading. Can you edit it to make the question appear clearer?

Comment: Hi, in the second question I asked how does spin-phonon coupling different from electron-phonon coupling? Thanks